# Managing a group of similar images in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app I need to manage groups of similar images, like on the example below:

[image: exampe]

Size of the group can be different (4x4, 2x2, 2x1 etc.), each square element can be either black or green. The resulting view is chosen by the given algorithm, so I need to create group of images with given size and given element colors, and manage it like single object (if it's possible - like single `ImageView`). What is the best way to do this? Is there any way to combine images without drawing them on view `Canvas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridView` is probably the best option.

Here's how you do it

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid);

    GridView gridview=(GridView)this.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    Integer[] mThumbIds;
    //pass the R.drawable ids to this function using your logic that chooses
    // the black and green etc.


    ImageAdapter myAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    myAdapter.SetImages(mThumbIds);
    gridview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use GridView for it and place ImageButton/Button in any place of GridView and  write a selector for Buttons and set it to all of your Buttons.